Работа Postman через ssh-bitvise tunnel с ключами
Настроил bitvise-ssh-client tunnel, чтобы был доступен необходимый ресурс, к которому имеется доступ через сервер клиента. При включенном туннеле через браузер доступ есть, через postman нет. Помогите понять, как должен быть настроен postman для этих целей и возможно ли это
